# populate textbox in jsp and pass parameter into it

Tags: report, birt

birt am currently doing report with Radio button and text box i.e 
how to populate textbox when radio button selected and I have to pass some text in text box and it have to get result of parameter for charts
for example

i )country is Radio button if I select then TextBox have to populate in that I will pass a "india" so it have to produce a total sale of that country

ii)City is Radio button if i select then TextBox have to populate in that I will pass a "Tamil nadu" so it have to produce a total sale of that City

and then while I enter some text in text box it have to auto search a word in it....

how can I pass parameter for this type Report?

so can u provide a solution in jsp file:

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly as you ask. What you could do is use cascading parameters. The top parameter would be your radio button list (country, city etc) and the second-level parameter can be a drop down list of countries/cities.

I'm not sure how to implement the search function you're looking for.